# Gen. 32:23 וַיָּקָם בַּלַּיְלָה הוּא = that night?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, vayishlach

*Vayishlach* [32](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/T0132):23 has:

> וַיָּקָם בַּלַּיְלָה הוּא וַיִּקַּח אֶת שְׁתֵּי נָשָׁיו וְאֶת שְׁתֵּי שִׁפְחֹתָיו וְאֶת אַחַד עָשָׂר יְלָדָיו וַיַּעֲבֹר אֵת מַעֲבַר יַבֹּק

The *Chizkuni* translates "וַיָּקָם בַּלַּיְלָה הוּא" as "he got up at night", with "הוּא" meaning "he", i.e. *Yaakov*. This is followed by [Rabbi Kaplan's translation](http://bible.ort.org/books/pentd2.asp?ACTION=displaypage&BOOK=1&CHAPTER=32#P951) as well as the *chumash* translation published in the more recent English translation of Rabbi S.R. Hirsch's *chumash* commentary.

However, the JPS, the *chumash* translation published in the old English translation of Rabbi Hirsch's *chumash* commentary, and ArtScroll's Stone Edition *chumash* translate "וַיָּקָם בַּלַּיְלָה הוּא" along the lines of "he got up *that* night" (emphasis supplied), as if it had said "וַיָּקָם בַּלַּיְלָה הַהוּא". My question is whether there's any classical (Jewish) support for this. That is, do any early Jewish commentaries/translations interpret the verse this way?

Comment: Check also Gen 19:33, 30:16 and I Sam 19:10 for other instances of those same two words.

Comment: I don't think we have a fixed rule about how many of the words in a definite phrase need a definite article, at least in Biblical Hebrew.

Comment: @DoubleAA those _p'sukim_ have the same phrase, but I want to know about this _pasuk_ specifically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @DoubleAA noted above, several other verses use the same language. Let's assume, though, that we cannot compare them, and that the phrase may change meaning based on context. Then we may only glean information from commentators' comments on this verse specifically. After perusing the sources, here are the *mefarshim* that support the "הוּא" == "הַהוּא" reading:

- [Radak](http://books.google.com/books?id=VIAtAAAAYAAJ&dq=%D7%A9%D7%93%D7%9C%20%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%AA&lr&as_brr=3&pg=PT146#v=onepage&q&f=false)
- [Ralbag](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=19168&st=&pgnum=80)
- [Michlol Yofi](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=33724&st=&pgnum=34) (R' Shlomo ibn Melech)
- [Mendelssohn's Biur](http://books.google.com/books?id=o-FDAAAAYAAJ&dq=%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%AA%20%D7%95%D7%91%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8&pg=PA430#v=onepage&q=%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%AA%20%D7%95%D7%91%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8&f=false) (R' Solomon Dubno)

It's up to you to choose which of these constitute "classical Jewish support".